# Galois Lagrange Resolvent and Root of Unity

Tags: galois-theory

Suppose $L/K$ is a cyclic field extension of degree $3$

Why does $K$ contain an element $\omega$ such that either $\omega$ or $\omega^2$ is a 3rd primitive root of unity?

Comment: @ancient mathematician Yes, we only know that $\omega \in k$

Comment: @ancientmathematician My text phrased it slightly awkwardly hence my confusion. It was stated that "pick and $\omega \in k$" then either $\omega$ or $\omega^2$ is a primitive root of unity. Which is what I was confued about. But I think what the author is trying to say is in my recent edit

Comment: I don't see it: with $L=\mathbb{F}_8$ and $K=\mathbb{F}_2$ I don't see primitive cube roots of unity anywhere.

Comment: There are also certainly cyclic extensions of $\mathbb{Q}$ of order 3, e.g. the real subfield of $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_7).$ Are you sure that there are no other hypotheses?